# CodeIgniter Auto Complete?

Tags: php, eclipse, codeigniter

I'm using Eclipse + Pdt . Is there any way to make Eclipse auto-complete the CI functions? 
e.g $this->db-> .. isn't being auto-completed for me and it would be swell if it did!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

http://7degrees.co.uk/blog/getting-full-auto-complete-with-codeigniter-in-eclipse/.
http://www.web-and-development.com/codeigniter-and-eclipse-autocomplete/ (my fav)
http://taggedzi.com/articles/display/autocomplete-eclipse-codeigniter-2

It should help.

Comment: Hmm ..it says there to look at either Base5.php or Base4.php and I don't have neither ..that blog is from 2 years ago it's possible some stuff changed in CI